# timeout command does not work with popen and output redirection

Tags: c, linux, bash, popen

I am using ssh to run a command on a remote host whose output I redirect to a file on my local host. I now need to use a timeout, but unable to use it for the command. The command is not getting executed, but instead the command is waiting for the timeout time (15 seconds). When I manually try this command on bash, it works. But, it does not work on popen (has that got to do anything with "sh -c cmd" ?).

```
    cmd = "timeout 15s sudo ip netns exec some_namespace ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o Loglevel=error admin@192.168.2.35 'remote_cmd remote_cmd_arg' > local_filename";

    if((pipe = popen(cmd, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf(stderr, "Error opening pipe\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: When you run it from your shell, are you copy-pasting the entire command directly from the program, or are you using a simplified version that you believe should work basically the same?

Comment: I am copy pasting the entire command. During prg execution, when i did a "ps -ef", i saw "sh -c cmd" (because of popen). I tried "sh -c cmd" on bash and that doesn't work either (it says "Try 'timeout --help' for more information.").

Comment: If you want to run `sh -c ..` from your shell, you have to escape your command properly: `sh -c "timeout 15s sudo ip netns exec some_namespace ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o Loglevel=error admin@192.168.2.35 'remote_cmd remote_cmd_arg' > local_filename"` (if your real command is different, you may have to escape it differently)

Comment: That isn't working either (putting cmd within quotes). The timeout command is returning 124 (exit status when given command times out). ps shows that "sh -c" is removing the quotes when executing the command. Even the single quote meant for ssh command is being removed.

Comment: The quotes are shell syntax and are not passed to the command. It's expected that `ps` does not show them.

Comment: ok, I did assume earlier that bash would know how to deal with quotes and that that may not be the cause of the issue. The thing is both the prg and my manual execution of the command are as the same user. This is why I am confused why it doesn't work when the prg executes it and works when I execute it.

Comment: Are you running this program in the same shell that you tested the command? Is it writing anything to stderr?

Comment: Yes. I tested by removing the "timeout 15s" from the command. The password prompt is now getting printed to my screen and the command works. So, it looks like timeout command is consuming the stdout of ssh ? Now, another question I have is when we use "> local_filename", we are using a bash construct to force stdout of ssh to local_filename. But then, how is the prompt getting printed to terminal ? I admit that my understanding of this has to improve. If the question/confusion is basic, sorry for that.

Comment: I found a way to get it work. I used "timeout --foreground 15s" instead and it works now. This allows the ssh command to interact with the terminal. I believe it otherwise would be a background process and may have been paused as soon as it wrote its ssh prompt to its stdout. Thank you for helping me out @thatotherguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied OP answer from the comments:

> I found a way to get it work. I used "timeout --foreground 15s"
> instead and it works now. This allows the ssh command to interact with
> the terminal. I believe it otherwise would be a background process and
> may have been paused as soon as it wrote its ssh prompt to its stdout.
> Thank you for helping me out @thatotherguy

Comment: @Janyanth, if you want to post this answer yourself, I will delete mine.